# After upgrading to Ubuntu 19.10, MySQL fails

Tags: mysql

My system offered to upgrade from 19.04 so I let it but many errors. Now MySQL will not run. Running this in terminal:

Ran: sudo *dpkg --remove --force-all mysql-community-client libmysqlclient21:amd64 mysql-common mysql-community-client-core*

```
dpkg: mysql-community-client: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 dbconfig-mysql depends on default-mysql-client | virtual-mysql-client; however:
  Package default-mysql-client is not installed.
  Package virtual-mysql-client is not installed.
  Package mysql-community-client which provides virtual-mysql-client is to be removed.

(Reading database ... 533508 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-community-client (8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10) ...
dpkg: libmysqlclient21:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 libvtk6.3 depends on libmysqlclient21 (>= 8.0.11); however:
  Package libmysqlclient21:amd64 is to be removed.
 libsnmp30:amd64 depends on libmysqlclient21 (>= 8.0.11).
 libqt4-sql-mysql:amd64 depends on libmysqlclient21 (>= 8.0.11).
 libgdal20 depends on libmysqlclient21 (>= 8.0.11).

Removing libmysqlclient21:amd64 (8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10) ...
Removing mysql-common (8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10) ...
Removing mysql-community-client-core (8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.30-0ubuntu2) ...
```

Then ran: *sudo apt install -f*

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dbconfig-mysql : Depends: default-mysql-client but it is not installed or
                           virtual-mysql-client
 libgdal20 : Depends: libmysqlclient21 (>= 8.0.11) but it is not installed
 libqt4-sql-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient21 (>= 8.0.11) but it is not installed
 libsnmp30 : Depends: libmysqlclient21 (>= 8.0.11) but it is not installed
 libvtk6.3 : Depends: libmysqlclient21 (>= 8.0.11) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Ran: *sudo dpkg --remove --force-all dbconfig-mysql; apt-get download libmysqlclient21; sudo dpkg -i libmysqlclient21*.deb; sudo apt install -f*

```
dpkg: dbconfig-mysql: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 phpmyadmin depends on dbconfig-mysql | dbconfig-no-thanks | dbconfig-common (<< 2.0.0); however:
  Package dbconfig-mysql is to be removed.
  Package dbconfig-no-thanks is not installed.
  Version of dbconfig-common on system is 2.0.11ubuntu2.

(Reading database ... 533425 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing dbconfig-mysql (2.0.11ubuntu2) ...
Get:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu eoan/mysql-8.0 amd64 libmysqlclient21 amd64 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10 [1,281 kB]
Fetched 1,281 kB in 8s (152 kB/s)                                              
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient21:amd64.
(Reading database ... 533424 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libmysqlclient21_8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient21:amd64 (8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmysqlclient21:amd64:
 libmysqlclient21:amd64 depends on mysql-common (>= 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10); however:
  Package mysql-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libmysqlclient21:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.30-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmysqlclient21:amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10)
 phpmyadmin : Depends: dbconfig-mysql but it is not installed or
                       dbconfig-no-thanks but it is not installed or
                       dbconfig-common (< 2.0.0) but 2.0.11ubuntu2 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Another error that pops up occasionally is:

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit -.mount is masked.
```

Comment: I tried that already and it tells me to run apt --fix-broken install but that gives the error Correcting dependencies... failed that I already posted. I think the other question you're referring to was for a different PC as I have four with Ubuntu. So far, I upgraded two and both have had issues with the process, this one with MySQL and the other with booting and app installation.

Comment: @Kulfy After following your suggestions and getting errors, they seemed somewhat minor so I rebooted the system. Once doing so, I ran _sudo apt install mysql-server_ and it seemed to install and start up as though nothing had happened! I can't log into it yet but maybe that's due to the new login that I need to change to the legacy login type as I understand that there is a new one on v8.X. Since I'm not sure what actually fixed it, I am unsure how to write it as an official Answer but please feel free to do so. Thank you and everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments:

1. Remove MySQL related packages *forcefully* using `dpkg`:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --remove --force-all mysql-server mysql-community-client mysql-common mysql-community-client-core libmysqlclient20 libmysqlclient21 mysql-client mysql-community-server-core mysql-community-server
   ```
2. Install MySQL again with APT:

   ```
   sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing `sudo apt install mysql-server` first, and after that `sudo apt install php-mysql`. I know it's weird, but it works.

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/LAMP/

Comment: When trying to install, it tells me that the mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.18-1ubuntu19.10). Both of the commands ask me if I want to continue and when I do, nothing is installed as it shows 0 as the amount of change.

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.14-1_all.deb
```

That will get you the latest package for Ubuntu Eoan (19.10).

On the install screen, choose the package:

[image: setup]

Finally, install the server:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```